# Expo Login with Google popup not open

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

Popup not opening in real device.

It's working smoothly on simulator and as well as in browser

My code is in React Native, app created from expo

I tried all possible but things but, as well I'm fresher. So, i have no more idea

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]